# Modern practice for client side javascript source structure with CommonJS TypeScript etc

Tags: javascript, client-side

My javascript foo is okay but I haven't kept up with the latest and greatest (we don't use Node.js in backend).

What is the modern practice of structuring client side javascript?

We organize javascript in sub directories with smaller files, and then minify and concatenate them for production.

When I check these popular client side js libraries

https://github.com/mbostock/d3

https://github.com/jquery/jquery

https://github.com/chriszarate/supergenpass

they are not written in client side javascript at all and it seems alien to me.

It seems like nowadays you have to learn commonjs and a slew of frameworks to comprehend and contribute.

I tried googling around but it returns a list of server side node.js related hits (grunt) but none talks about using it to maintain a client side library.

Any good pointers?

Comment: It's a great question and a journey I took a few months ago, but sadly, probably too broad/open-ended for SO. Learning about [WebPack](http://webpack.github.io/) or [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) would be a great place to start.

Comment: Agreed. The SO gods frown upon this kind of posting.  Short answer look into AngularJS, it foster good coding practices, and test driven development.

Comment: Hint #2: You'll probably want to figure out how to integrate Grunt/Gulp into your IDE so it can coordinate the build process.

Answer (score 0):

So I've been doing more research. It seems like the answer is in CommonJS and node.js

Some client side frameworks use CommonJS to break code into modules (which most browsers won't understand), and use node.js and package manager like bowsify to combine these modules into a single javascript file.